# Isotropic classical model with a different phase transition than its anisotropic quantum limit

Tags: phase-transition, spin-models, phase-diagram

I have often heard that the isotropic ferromagnetically-coupled 2d classical Ising model and the quantum 1d transverse field Ising model have similar phases and the same universality class of their phase transitions because of a classical-to-quantum mapping between them.

That is, if we introduce anisotropy by allowing the couplings in the vertical direction of the classical Ising model to become very weak and the couplings in the horizontal direction to become very strong, keeping an appropriate function of them fixed, then the transfer matrix of the classical model is well-approximated by an exponential of the quantum Hamiltonian.

However, I feel like in this procedure we are introducing an extreme anisotropy, and a priori I wouldn't have expected the quantum model and the original isotropic classical model to have the same phases and universality classes of their phase transition. There are some special properties to the Ising model, like Kramers-Wannier duality, that perhaps help the connection even in the anisotropic limit, but I'm more interested in whether I can find a counterexample.

Are there examples of isotropic classical models with phase transitions for which the corresponding quantum model in an appropriate anisotropic limit suffers different phase transitions? I have in mind models with Ising spins that have a vertical direction for which the vertical couplings are Ising-type, but the within-plane couplings can be more general, and I'm open to examples with more degrees of freedom per site.